# Can not edit code in xpages or custom control

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse, xsp

I have a problem with Domino Designer since the problem occurs not only in existing xpage and databases, it also happens in newly created databasen and xpages as well as custom controls.

The problem is that when I try to open an xpage or custom control, I will not se any code, or anything but an emppty blank page under the toolbars.

First I thought it could be my screen, then I thought it could be an configuration problem so I reconfigured the notes client and tried again, then I check if I could open the custom controls with the xml editor instead of the xsp editor, and that worked, but I want the xsp editor back.

What is this, a blank page, it seems that it could not render properly, because if I use my keyboard and pressing the space bar, then it ask me if I want to save the changes when closing the custom control by the esc.

Do I have to re-install the client? Or does it exist any configurations for the xsp editor I miss?

BTW, It happens the other day, and when I re-configured my installation it worked, but this time it does not.

Comment: A screenshot here would help us help you.

Comment: It was absolutely white, blank over the whole screen, exept for that the menu and the toolbars in the designer was visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking at the design pane and not the source pane? At the bottom of the blank page, above the properties area there are two tabs, click on the "source" tab.

If that's not the issue, I'm not sure what's going wrong

Comment: Could not switch between the design or source pane. Everything was just a white page. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I did not have time to investigate any further, it must have been the render function of the XSP Editor that was corrupt, stopped working and I re-installed the Notes and Designer and then I could continue working. No problems in my code. :-)

Comment: Please accept Brian's answer if you think he has helped you. It's a way of saying thank you to people who take time and make an effort to respond to questions.